# Mail-in db with attachments not appearing in the Body field

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a mail-in database application and I am finding that occasionally an email is received with an attachment that is not part of the Body field and therefor not able to be "seen" by rtItem.EmbeddedObjects.

How do I identify that there is an attachment if it is not in the Body and once I do that how do I get a handle on it?

I need to determine the type of attachment (PDF, JPG, DOC, XLS, etc.), detach it and then process it based on the extension.

Here is the various If statements that do all the checking of the Body (RTF) field and the associated EmbeddedObjects. This does not catch an attachment that is "outside" of the Body.

```
Set rtItem = mailDoc.Getfirstitem("Body")
        If ( rtItem.Type = RICHTEXT ) Then
            If Not (IsEmpty(rtItem.EmbeddedObjects)) Then    
                ForAll o In rtItem.EmbeddedObjects
                    If (o.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT) Then
                        noAttachment = True                            
                    Else
                        noAttachment = True                            
                    End If                        
                End ForAll
            Else
                noAttachment = True                            
            End if
        Else
            noRTF = True
        End If
```

I also have a document with nothing in the Body but $File contains the attachment name. How do you find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youll need to get at those attachments using the EmbeddedObjects property of the NotesDocument.  The union of that property plus all the EmbeddedObjects properties of all rich text items gives you access to all the attachments.  Note that usually you only need to worry about the Body rich text item.

Comment: Your comments pointed me in the right direction. I never knew there was an EmbeddedObjects property in NotesDocument. Thank you.

Comment: It's a leftover from Notes V2!  These attachments generally show up below a solid line that is drawn across the bottom of the document.

Answer (score 0):

FYI we've hit a similar problem when the mail server was running out of disk space, or if a virus scanner blocked access to the attachment